# How to delete an option tag in a variable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

Deleting an option tag in DOM is not a problem for me, but now I have to delete an option Tag in a variable. This is what I have:

```
var txt = "<select name='example'><option value='1'>Test</option></select>";
$(txt).find("select option[value='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").remove();
```

The selector seems to be right, i've debugged it with text() and it gives me the right value. But the variable txt doesn't change - what did I do wrong?

Comment: Apart from other problems, the selected element in `$(text)` is **`select`**, which does not have a `select` element has descendant hence `.find()` does not find any elements.

Comment: You don't need to define the `select` in the `find` call because the jQuery object is the `select` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a jQuery selector to start with to save yourself having to constantly cast it again into one.

In your find you also don't need to specify `select` again as you are executing `.find()` on the select.

For simplicity I cached the result of the `.find()` into a nother selector variable before removing it.

The below works fine. Well, it works fine if I use `1` instead of `$(this).attr("id")` as I don't know what you are refering to with `$(this)`.

```
var $txt = $("<select name='example'><option value='1'>Test</option></select>");
//var $option = $txt.find("option[value='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']");
var $option = $txt.find("option[value='" + 1 + "']"); // selects option with value of 1
$option.remove(); // Removes option
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn3vQ/)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `select` in your selector. And you have to use `$()` to make it a jQuery object first. After that you can manipulate it.

```
var txt = "<select name='example'><option value='1'>Test</option></select>",
    $txt = $(txt);
$txt.find("option[value='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were expecting the value of `txt` to change it won't - jQuery will not change it (it couldn't; it is passed by value, not reference), it will merely make a pseudo-DOM from it and remove the option. Nothing permanent happens, though.

If you want to retrieve the affected result, you'll need to have the whole thing in container and read back its HTML:

```
var txt = "<p>this is a HTML <span>string</span></p>";
txt = $('<div />').append(txt).find('span').remove().end().html();
```

`txt` now has the `span` removed.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, `txt` is still just a `String`. I guess you want that DOM snippet in a variable, which would be this:

```
var txt = "<select name='example'><option value='1'>Test</option></select>";
var $domSnippet=$(txt);
domSnippet.find("select option[value='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").remove();
```

Comment: That won't work, since `select` is the selected element, it does not have a `select` descendant.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting with a string containing some HTML, stored in your `txt` variable. When you call `$(txt)` you're creating a jQuery object containing the elements defined in that HTML string, which is completely separate from your `txt` variable. You can then manipulate (in this case attempt to remove) elements, but since it's completely separate from `txt` the changes aren't going to be reflected in it.

If you want to change the value of `txt` to be something else, you'll need to assign that value back to it, possibly like so (you mentioned that calling `.text()` gave you what you expected/wanted to see):

```
txt = $(txt).find("select option[value='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").remove().text();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution results just the value of the option tag, this was one of the solutions I've tested before.

Answer (score 0):

the remove() method removes elements - so they have to be in the DOM , since txt is a variable its not represented in the DOM, the value is merely a string . you should use something like replace().

```
var txt = "<select name='example'><option value='1'>Test</option></select>";
        txt=txt.replace("<select name='example'><option value='1'>Test</option></select>","replacedText");
```